# Parse Table View Cells Blank

Tags: swift, tableview, parse-server, cells

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class AmbianceTableViewTableViewController: UITableViewController,                UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate{
    //variables
    var name = [String]()
    var carBrand = [String]()
    var carEngine = [String]()

    //Properties
    @IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Query data for Table
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        let query = PFQuery(className: "Make")
        query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            }else{
                if let make = objects {
                    for objects in make {
                        if let make = objects as? PFObject {
                            let name = make["name"] as! String

                            print(make["name"])
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return name.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Ambiance", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

        cell.venueNameLabel.text = name[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello I am new to Swift... What I'm trying to do here is perform a query and get the objects within that class and update the UI labels with the parse data. Everything works EXCPET when I its time to display the parsed info from the object to the label created. The cells all return blank.

Comment: Couple of things, Your name array is never being populated. Where you print the make["name"] value you should have name.apped(name). Then you have the problem of reloading the tableView before the query is finished. Move the reloadTableView line above the inside the query. (Before the  '})' line above it.) I'll add in an answer to explain it better

Comment: Hello I am new to Swift... What I'm trying to do here is perform a query and get the objects within that class and update the UI labels with the parse data. Everything works EXCPET when I its time to display the parsed info from the object to the label created. The cells all return blank. Its been a couple days and I cannot seem to figure out why. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You are never adding anything to your name array so your tableView will never show any data. Also, when the  query is finished you then need to call reloadData. You currently call is after the async call which would mean your reloading your table before the data is returned.

Change your query to this,

```
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Make")
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { [weak self] (objects, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }else{
            if let allCarMakes = objects {
                for carMake in allCarMakes {
                    if let make = carMake["name"] as? String {
                        self?.name.append(make)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
```

Comment: That call to `reloadData` must be made on the main queue.

Comment: Why? it will work fine without moving it to the main queue.

Comment: No. All UI updates *must* be done on the main queue. This completion block will be called on a background queue.

Comment: Ive updated my answer, but to clarify for myself. Would Apple reject an app that reloads a table on a background thread.

Comment: It's not an issue of being rejected, it's an issue of the app working correctly or not.

Comment: I see, but I  have never called a reload on the main thread on all my parse queries and have never experienced any issues. Albeit, I have the query subclassed and use completion blocks to return the data.

Comment: THANK YOU DEVSTER101! That worked Perfectly. Awesome dude.

Comment: Yea, how do you accept an answer? Sorry, I'm new here too.

Comment: One more thing, how would i do a query  to have multiple objects within a single class (of lets say "Make") display on each of the corresponding labels?. Each objectid has multiple columns of data that corresponds to a single make (i.e. type, color, etc.) Thanks for the help!

Comment: To accept an answer you need to click on the tick icon to the left of my question. On your other question, that is a conversation for real time chat. As I don't quite understand what you need. Do you mean you want to have pointers to other classes inside your Make class that has corresponding data to that particular make?